# MySQL Update multiple rows VS Insert update on duplicate key, Which one is faster?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I can update multiple rows in two ways, I think so.

1. Calling update query several times to update rows.
2. Calling one Insert query with On Depulicated Key Update.

Which one is faster?
Let's assume that we are handling a big database and we are updating lots of rows.

Thanks!

Comment: What did your tests show?

Comment: Ther is more than 2 mentioned ways. Some of them are available only in 8+ version, some are applicable in 5+ version.

Comment: Maybe you are right! I am on 5+ versions and my main concern is which one is faster for the above 2 methods.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide an example of multiple updates vs one IODKU.  There could be subtle issues that have a big impact on the comparison.  `IN(...)` comes to mind.

In general, there is "a lot" of overhead *per statement*.  That says 1 query is likely to beat several queries.

A specific example:  100 single-row `INSERTs` takes about 10 times as long as one `INSERT` with 100 rows in it.

Check to see if the queries are inside a transaction, versus simply run with autocommit=ON.  If not already in a transaction, you can gain some speed by sticking BEGIN and COMMIT around the batch of write commands.  (With simply autocommit=ON, *each* write is effectively a transaction.  The above replaces the overhead for many transactions into one.)

Comment: I am going to use this for the only updates.
So for example, if I need to update 100 rows, then I will have to run UPDATEs about 100 times.
In another way, I can update 100 rows by only one INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATAE. 
So I am wondering which one is faster.
100 Updates VS 1 Insert on duplicate update

Comment: It depends on how many rows, where the update values come from (eg, another table), how spread out the rows to change are, etc.

Comment: I have all data. no need to pull data from another table. fields are approximately 15. What do you think?

Comment: @Pavel - If you are changing 15 _columns_ in _one_ row, then one `UPDATE` should suffice.  If you mean 15 _rows_, then I contend that 15 `UPDATEs` would be fast enough and simple enough.  If you are updating 1000 rows, we can discuss further.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. so one UPDATE query would update 15 columns in the row.
And I would run these UPDATE queries 100 times. So I need to update 100 rows.

Comment: @Pavel - So, next question -- Does it take "too long" to run 100 separate updates?  Or is it too tedious to write 100 updates?  [I would certainly grumble about writing that much.]  Are you generating these updates in some programming language (Java/PHP/...); if not, is it reasonable to do so?

Comment: It is sometimes possible, but messy, to have a single IODKU handle 100 rows.  It is sometimes possible to have 1 update do 100 rows.  There is no "one size fits all".  So, to go down that path, I will need to see some samples of the updates.  (Please add them to your Question so they will be available to other Answerers.)  I will look for a pattern in the updates, then (hopefully) propose a solution.

Comment: The main concern is the performance.
I am using sequelize and nothing to be afraid about any queries.
Just we noticed that there're bunch of update request and thought if we could this in bulkUpdate, it can improve the performance. That's the start point. thanks.

Comment: @Pavel - I added a paragraph about decreasing the overhead for transactions.

Comment: I think sequelize already handles it. When I see the log, it START TRANSACTION and then running queries.